# How to add struts2 tags in spring jsp page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to use struts-jquery-tags in Spring jsp page or suggest some other Spring tags. for usage of sj:div with action targets some other div.

Answer (score 0):

Add the relative tlds and library files in your classpath and refer to them from your JSP. This works for any tag that you may want to use inside your JSPs

Comment: No, this works for any tags that don't rely on anything in the framework they're designed for.

Comment: i had add the struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1.jar, in JSP page add <%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %> then using sj:div tag getting follow error....Saif Asif...javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/ui/AbstractClosingTag

Answer (score 0):

The S2 jQuery tags are dependent on the S2 framework as they currently stand.

You would need to emulate the OGNL value stack exposed via S2 interceptors.

Is there a compelling reason to not just write JavaScript?

Comment: I want function for the <a href="action" tagert="someDivID">Click</a> <dibv id="someDivID"></div>.Dave Newton how to reach the above code.